# Show Angular Pipe Possible Options in HTML

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

Is there a way to show some extra options/helpers when calling an angular pipe in HTML, among the function/pipe parameters?

For example:

[image: search pipe angular / HTML view]

I can see the parameters, but the **searhType** is being used as a switch case to filter different types of search. I would like to add help with the description of possible cases for the **searchType** parameter.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try in your pipe to change `searchType?: string` with `searchType?: Type_1 | Type_2 | Type_N`

Comment: `searchType: SearchTypes` - SearchTypes should be an enum

Comment: @Emilien, thanks for the suggestion. Seems like a good option to show predefined values instead of letting developers scroll through the pipe and search for the **searchTypes**, or misspelling searchType when calling the pipe. Also, I would like to have some kind of comments in the screenshot above to explain the methods along with the suggested values.